# How to replace celery default logger with TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging, celery

I've been battling with this all day. I have read dozens of stackoverflow and other posts. Many of the suggestions do not work and none address directly what I want to do. So I will post this and answer it for the benefit of anybody else struggling.

Imagine your celery worker tasks and your beat scheduler all work fine. Using default construction methods you will be stuck with 2 logfiles defined by, e.g. :

```
celery worker ..... -f ./logs/celeryworker.log
celery beat ..... -f ./logs/celerybeat.log
```

These will just grow indefinitely. How can I introduce a rotating log?

Answer (score 6):

The default celery `logging.FileHandler` is a `WatchedFileHandler`. We want to use a `TimedRotatingFileHandler` from `logging.handlers`. So we use the celery signal `after_setup_logger` in our tasks file to accomplish the following :

```
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger

@after_setup_logger.connect
def replace_handler(**kwargs_):
    logger = kwargs_['logger'] if 'logger' in kwargs_ else None
    if logger and logger.handlers:
        handler_celery = logger.handlers[-1]
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(handler_celery.baseFilename, 'midnight', 1)
        handler.setFormatter(handler_celery.formatter)
        logger.handlers[-1] = handler
```

Now this resets both the worker and beat logger. I have tested this using 2 minute intervals in the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` constructor, so I assume it works for overnight rotation.

**EDIT1: 25/09/2019**

Thanks to Tomáš Linhart - I shall look into `logrotate`.
I was up coding tonight, so I checked that the log indeed rotates overnight.
I also updated the code slightly to be a bit safer.
I have quite a simple setup : concurrency=1 where I need a FIFO queue of tasks to be processed sequentially, so maybe this simple solution masks potential problems pointed out by Tomáš.

**EDIT2: 25/09/2019**

I have spent time looking into this. There are still several problems : `WatchedFileHandler` is linux only and can still suffer from race conditions, while `logrotate` itself can also suffer from race conditions. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes explains multi-process logging and https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html explains how to use a `QueueListener` rather than creating your own `multiprocessing.Process`. Putting this all together I have created a multi-process class wrapper for the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` :

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener, TimedRotatingFileHandler
from multiprocessing import Queue as MQueue
import multiprocessing.queues
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger
from atexit import register

class QueuedTimedRotatingFileHandler:
    instance = None

    def __init__(self, filename_, formatter_):
        self.queue = MQueue(-1)
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename_, 'midnight', 1)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter_)
        self.listener = QueueListener(self.queue, handler)
        self.listener.start()
        register(self.stop)

    def stop(self):
        self.listener.stop()

@after_setup_logger.connect
def replace_handler(**kwargs_):
    logger = kwargs_['logger'] if 'logger' in kwargs_ else None
    if logger and logger.handlers:
        handler_celery = logger.handlers[-1]
        if QueuedTimedRotatingFileHandler.instance is None:
            QueuedTimedRotatingFileHandler.instance = \
                QueuedTimedRotatingFileHandler(
                    handler_celery.baseFilename,
                    handler_celery.formatter
                )
        handler = QueueHandler(QueuedTimedRotatingFileHandler.instance.queue)
        logger.handlers[-1] = handler
```

This now feels like the safest and most elegant cross-platform solution. Any comments welcome.

**EDIT3: 26/09/2019**

Last change I think, have altered the code above. Needed to construct the wrapper like a singleton because celery worker can parse file multiple times.

**EDIT4: 02/10/2019**

One last change. Stopping the listener needs to be registered with `atexit` to be triggered correctly.

Comment: You will find a lot of material online about problems using `TimedRotatingFileHandler` in multiprocessing Python application (which is a case of Celery). Therefore it's adviced to use `WatchedFileHandler` with a tool like `logrotate` instead.